# Google SDK iOS - sign() method completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

In iOS Google SDK I failed to find a relevant method to handle events when signIn process succeeds.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) { }
```

This method does not take completion handler as parameter, is there any other API method that can handle SignIn process completion?

I failed to find anything in docs, also Google's official tutorial is quite desultory.

Why I need this? 
I create separate `GoogleManager` class for handling google Sign In process, and I want to pass a completion handler from my VC to perform segue when done. How should one approach it?

Comment: There isn't any method with completion handler in Google SDK

Comment: You can add NotificationObserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one delegate for your custom `GoogleManager` and create instance of that delegate inside that `GoogleManager` and implement that delegate on class where you are creating instance of your custom class `GoogleManager`, after that when `GIDSignInDelegate` method called use your custom delegate and called its method. So it should look something like this.

```
protocol GoogleManagerDelegate {
     func receiveResponse(user: GIDGoogleUser)// Pass Parameter that you want
}
```

Now in `GoogleManager` class when you get response in `GIDSignInDelegate` method you need to call `GoogleManagerDelegate` method.

```
class GoogleManager {
     var delegate: GoogleManagerDelegate?

     //Your other method     

     func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) { 
         self.delegate?.receiveResponse(user: user)
     }
}
```

Now implement the `GoogleManagerDelegate` inside your controller where your creating instance of `GoogleManager` and set its delegate instance to self.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GoogleManagerDelegate {

    //Your other methods     

    func googleSignIn() {
        let googleManager = GoogleManager()
        googleManager.delegate = self
    }

    //GoogleManagerDelegate method
    func receiveResponse(user: GIDGoogleUser) {
        //Access user object here
    }
}
```

Comment: @DCDC Why you have created sharedGIDSignIn ? and what it is for, i have not mention anything about it in my answer.

Comment: @DCDC Welcome mate :)